# Database Meaning of one Constraint

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

Anyone Could Describe for me what is the meaning of `QTY > QTY(500)` in following sentence?

```
CONSTRAINT DBC1 IS_EMPTY
((S JOIN SP) WHERE STATUS<20 AND QTY>QTY(500));
```

I translate it: status is lower than 20 and quantity is bigger that 500.

please note that just I need meaning of QTY> QTY(500)...

Comment: do you already have this constraint on your table? and do you already have any data in your table ? because mathematically `QTY>QTY(500)` can never evaluate to true. Also what RDBMS are you using ? MySQL , SQL Server, Oracle ??

Comment: Dear @M.Ali, would you please say with any value, what is the meaning of this sentence? QTY>QTY(500)? I has a problem with meaning...without considering constraint and data.

Comment: The meaning is simple value of `QTY` is greater than `QTY times 500` which will never be true. Even if `QTY = 0` or `QTY IS NULL`.

Comment: it means 500 types of objects or if we have object A that has quantity 540, so A has QTY > 500 ? it's so simple?

Comment: No if it was only `QTY > 500` then it would mean the `QTY` column should always have a value greater than 500. But this expression `QTY>QTY(500)` means what ever the value of `QTY` is should be greater than when the value of `QTY` is multiplied with 500. Now this is never going to evaluate to true.

Comment: I'm not sure that u be right... Dear @M.Ali

Comment: I am pretty darn sure what I am talking about. do you actually have any data in your table ?

Comment: @Dr.Jackson . . . This syntax is not syntax that I am familiar with for a constraint (`S JOIN SP` ???).  As for the idea that `QTY > QTY * 500` is never true.  First, you need the `*` for this to be multiplication.  Second, with the `*`, this is true for all negative numbers.

Comment: Dear @GordonLinoff, I mentioned from Date Book, IS_EMPTY ( ( S JOIN SP ) WHERE STATUS < 20 AND QTY > QTY ( 500 ) ) ; ("no supplier with status less than 20 can supply any part in a quantity greater than 500").

Comment: Dear @M.Ali, please see, http://books.google.com/books?id=zUebAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA52&dq=QTY+%3E+QTY+%28+500+%29+constraint+database&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EAg7VKGJDsO_ywPHxYCQDQ&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=QTY%20%3E%20QTY%20%28%20500%20%29%20constraint%20database&f=false

Comment: Dear @GordonLinoff, please see, http://books.google.com/books?id=zUebAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA52&dq=QTY+%3E+QTY+%28+500+%29+constraint+database&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EAg7VKGJDsO_ywPHxYCQDQ&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=QTY%20%3E%20QTY%20(%20500%20)%20constraint%20database&f=false

Comment: Note that the language used here is _NOT_ SQL.  QTY(500) stands for the number 500, but it needs the typing construct because the concerned attribute (QTY) is declared to be of type QTY.  Slightly confusing at first, but not impossible.  Your "translation" is correct.

Comment: Dear @ErwinSmout, would you please describe a bit more detail as an answer of this question, my professor translate: status lower 20 and QTY > 500 for each type of products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(S JOIN SP) contains a tuple for each shipment, and this tuple is "extended" with the details of the supplier, such as his status code.

The [result of the restriction defined by the] WHERE clause thus amounts to "shipments of quantity >500 whose corresponding supplier's status is <20".

The declaration overall thus says "there cannot be any shipments of quantity >500 whose corresponding supplier's status is <20.